# HVAC condensation drain and weird concrete bulge

Tags: hvac, concrete, drain, condensation

Does anyone know why I developed a bulge on my concrete near my condensation drain? And what is that copper pipe coming up from the floor?[image]

Comment: I would suspect tree roots

Comment: Where does the copper pipe ho, above ground?

Comment: "Water and sewer lines must be a minimum of ten feet apart; they are not to be laid in the same trench. When a potable water line crosses a sewer line, the requirement is to provide two feet or more of clearance."https://krwa.net/portals/krwa/lifeline/1211/82.pdf  - It'd had better be the T&P discharge line, (but even that would be wrong; T&P pipes are to terminate w/o threads, directed at a drain, at no more than 6" above it) but it's almost certainly the incoming or the outgoing and that drain pipe is totally absent.

Comment: There isn't really a question here until all your guests start getting food poising from drinking your water.

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/104674/does-the-height-of-a-water-heater-safety-valve-matter/104675#104675

Comment: I don’t believe that drain is connected to my sewer. From what I’ve been reading many times condensation drains just go through the slab and into the ground/dirt to be absorbed. That seems to be my case. 

As for the copper pipe, I was referring to the stub of one that looks sawed off. The full one is the in water line. And I do have whole house water filters plus an RO system for drinking, but thank you for your concern.

Comment: The one that's cut off is one that failed and got replaced (assuming it's not some defunct floor heat or w/e). If you're right about it not actually being a drain (and still somewhat, even if it is) then it's exposing the pipe to moisture on the outside where it's in contact with the grade. Which would explain why it's been replaced already. And if it's just been getting *leaked at* for 20y, then yeah, funny stuff might start to happen to the floor. At the very least it's going to delaminate the vinyl from the concrete and start to show the slop-job around the pipes it's been hiding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concrete does not bulge , it will crack.  I do not see a crack.

If you are referring to the area where the sheet vinyl has peeled up, that is the result of moisture getting under the vinyl, mold and mildew growing and the glue failing.

A solution would be to trim the vinyl away from the drain by about 4 inches.
(cut away the loose vinyl too.) Clean the area well. Seal the edges of the vinyl with [polyurethane caulk](https://metrosealant.com/product/vulkem-116-tubes/?attribute_color=Gray&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=20459101807&utm_content=&utm_term=&gad=1&gclid=CjwKCAjwr_CnBhA0EiwAci5sirk1cGpVNMyvyWyA1dhBui3MVpj5_RTnGGzPeu86kSo5eOTYhBUtsRoCSGcQAvD_BwE). Then used concrete sealer or paint to seal the area not covered by vinyl.

This will seal the vinyl from further water intrusion.  It's not particularly pretty looking, but I assume it's a basement and the utility of the area is more important.

The copper pipe is abandoned plumbing. Former use unknown.

Comment: Yep, if there's a bulge in the concrete, it was there when it was poured.

Comment: Funny I don’t recall any bump/bulge there before. But maybe it was. I too didn’t think concrete can bulge, but since not recalling it there before I thought maybe. Thank you for your inputs.

Comment: It is not uncommon for the poured concrete around pipes to be a bit higher than the  whole floor.  It's just difficult to get the concrete as flat around obstacles.